# Parsing JSON with an optional object?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have the following script:

```
var argv = process.argv.splice(2);
var obj = argv[0];
var pkg = require("./package.json");

console.log(pkg.obj);
```

I want my script to parse for whatever `obj` equals, not `obj` itself. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand your question, but are you looking for `pgk[obj]` maybe?

Comment: @mmm that solved it! Thanks so much! Feel free to answer the question with that, and I'll accept.

Comment: @mmm awesome! I accepted, again, thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do what you want, you can use bracket notation:

```
console.log(pkg[obj]);
```